# Determine if the relation: ‘is greater than or equal to’ on the set of all integers

Tags: set-theory

Determine if the relation: ‘is greater than or equal to’ on the set
of all integers.

**Reflexive**

Let $A = \{1,\{1\},\{2\},3,\{3\}\}$, how does one determine this correctly outlining the steps to document this?

For all integers: $\forall x : x \geq x$. According to the book, it is **Reflexive**. But, it does not document this steps properly. So, I am asking here in the hope that there's someone that knows the insides and outsides of this.

Comment: unclear. “Determine if [noun]” is not a question. What does the set A have to do with anything?

Comment: This is because $x=x$ for all $x$. Do you see why that must be reflexive?

Comment: @CyclotomicField, **No!** I don't. Please explain, thanks?

Comment: @AlbinM equality is an equivalence relation, which is always reflexive.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, how do you show this mathematically?

Comment: @AlbinM You don't, it's part of the definition. When you define something you don't have to prove it is that way, you just have to ensure it exists. For any non-empty $X$ set then the diagonal elements $\{(x,x), x \in X\} \subset X^2$ can be included in a relation to make it reflexive, so reflexive relations exist and two of them are $=$ and $\geq$, again by definition.

Comment: So, what about the set **A** above, which includes *set in set* ? This part is confusing here.

Comment: @AlbinM I have no idea what $A$ is or what it has to do with relations.